# How to set a base path for SCSS imports in SvelteKit?

Tags: javascript, sass, svelte, sveltekit

I want to import an scss file in one of my components. Is there a way to use aliases or something else so I can import them without a long relative path.

For example, rather than this:
`<style lang='scss'> @use '../../../styles/main.scss' </style>`

I would like to do something like this instead:
`<style lang='scss'> @use '@/styles/main.scss' </style>`

I'm using the sass a svelte-preprocess packages.

This works in Vue but not sure if a similar thing is possible in svelte.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself so I can't say for certain that it works, but it might work if you put it in `src/lib/styles/main.scss` and import it like `@use '$lib/styles/main.scss'`

Comment: @Tholle Thanks, this does indeed seem to work. I have been experimenting with other options to get it to work as well and I think I have figured it out. I'll post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so after quite a lot of googling and experimenting, I think I have come up with a solution.

Firstly I switched to using the [vitePreprocess](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors-vitepreprocess) processor rather than svelte-preprocess. As per the instructions, `svelte.config.js` needed to be edited to look like this:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    },
    preprocess: [vitePreprocess()] // Add this line and its import (above)
};

export default config;
```

Then in `vite.config.js` edit it as follows:

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite'
import path from 'path'

/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */
const config = {
    plugins: [
        sveltekit()
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': path.resolve('src') // Styles in src/styles will be accessible as '@/styles/whatever.scss'
        }
    }
}

export default config
```

This achieves my goal though hot module reload doesn't quite work correctly. Changes to the scss file don't trigger an automatic reload. There are probably a few options but I like the following which uses the `vite-plugin-restart` module to watch the styles folder and restart the server when one of those files changes.

First:

```
npm install --save-dev vite-plugin-restart
```

Then further edit `vite.config.js` to look something like this:

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite'
import VitePluginRestart from 'vite-plugin-restart'
import path from 'path'

// No idea why this is needed
// The default export of vite-plugin-restart looks to be the function but it doesn't work when imported
// Need to access the 'default' key from the imported object instead
const ViteRestart = VitePluginRestart.default

/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */
const config = {
    plugins: [
        sveltekit(),
        ViteRestart({
            restart: [
                'src/styles/*.scss' // For some reason path.resolve doesn't seem to work here
            ]
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': path.resolve('src')
        }
    }
}

export default config
```

The vite server will be restarted whenever you edit one of the scss files.

Comment: Do you happen to know if this answer is still current as of 2024? I see lots of examples elsewhere on the internet suggesting setting `config.preprocess.scss.includePaths` but I'm having trouble making it work.